# Unable to change the image of UItableviewcell Button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using UITableView with a checkbox button in every cell. When user taps on that cell or button, the image of that button must change to the 'selected' image. But when I taps on any cell or button, the image is not getting changed.

Here is my table code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : categoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("categoryCell") as! categoryCell
    let dic : NSDictionary = categoryitem.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
    cell.category_name.text = dic.valueForKey("category_name") as? String


    return cell

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categoryitem.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell : categoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("categoryCell") as! categoryCell

    cell.category_button.setImage(UIImage(named: "check_checkbox"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    let dic : NSDictionary = categoryitem.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
    print(dic.valueForKey("category_id") as! String)
}
```

Comment: Have you created IBOutlet for imageView in categoryCell???

Comment: but i want to change the image of uibutton. so i create iboutlet of uibutton @SandeepBhandari

Comment: Sorry I meant UIButton :D

Comment: yes i did@SandeepBhandari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath as

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell : categoryCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! categoryCell

    cell.category_button.setImage(UIImage(named: "check_checkbox"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    let dic : NSDictionary = categoryitem.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
    print(dic.valueForKey("category_id") as! String)
}
```

**Mistake you did**

```
let cell : categoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("categoryCell") as! categoryCell
```

will return you the cell for reuse but you need to access the currently loaded cell at indexPath where user tapped :) So use cellForRowAtIndexPath.
cellForRowAtIndexPath returns the currently loaded cell at indexPath

Answer (score 0):

You need to add target to your button checkbox in cellForRowAtIndexPath method
in the button call back you can change image.  like this

```
[cell.checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 checkbutton.tag=indexpath.row;
-(void)buttonclick:(id)sender
{`
// you can change your image here..
}
```

Comment: but how can i access button in that function?

Comment: like how can i define cell outside method?

Comment: @Jack.Right You are getting button reference there as Sender

Comment: sorry but i can't get it can you please write down code for access uibutton outside of cell for row at indexpath method

Comment: --(void)buttonclick:(UIButton)sender  {     sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
      }  check it